# MySQL how to get the desired result

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables.

Table Product (P)

```
id   name
1     x
2     y
3     z
```

Table detail.  (D)

```
id   rate productId
1     5     1
2     9     2
3     10    1
4     12    2
5     14    1
6     10    3
```

I'm unable to write a query to obtain the desired result.

The desired output is this.

```
 productId  Name  CurrentDetailId  currentRate  LastDetailId    last Rate  
    1        x        5                14            3             10
    2        y        4                12            2              9
    3        z        6                10            Null          Null
```

I write this query

```
 SELECT p.Id, p.Name, MAX(d.Id) AS CurrentDetailId , MAX(d2.id) AS LastDetailId, d.Rate ,  d2.Rate 
 FROM  Product p 
   INNER JOIN detail d ON d.productId = p.Id
   INNER JOIN detail d2 ON d.Id > d2.Id AND d.productId= d2.productId
   GROUP BY d.productId
```

But this query work with `INNER JOIN` will not list the product 3.

I want all the products. if there is not last Rate then simply set to blanks or null.

Here current rate will be the Max detailId against `productId` and Last Rate will be the 2nd max `detailId` against `productId`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select p.Id,p.Name, 
(SELECT Rate FROM detail WHERE productId=p.Id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS last_rate, 
(SELECT Rate FROM detail WHERE productId=p.Id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS current_rate 
from  Product p
```

Here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58861d/20)

Comment: your solutions works fine. but  one question what if i want to select
more then once column from detail table.
i.E.
"SELECT Rate,Id,xyz FROM detail WHERE productId=@my_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1"
 how to accomplish this task ?

Comment: @sm.abdullah you will have to copy the select and change column name for each column you want, you cannot select multiple columns at once in 1 select

Comment: but unfortunately I have 9 to 10 columns. do not you think it will be a performance issue ?

Comment: and consider the size of the detail table in hundred of thousands.

Comment: @sm.abdullah I considered the data you showed... And in all cases the subqueries won't be heavy as you're selecting by `key` and limiting to 1 result. In all cases I don't see any other way that will be less heavy

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another possibility:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.Rates,',',1) AS currentRate, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.Rates,',',-1) AS lastRate
FROM Product p JOIN
(SELECT productId, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Rate order by Id DESC),',',2) as Rates
FROM detail GROUP BY productId) r
ON p.Id=r.productId;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebf5f0/1

For this query to perform, it is important that Product.Id, detail.Id and detail.productId are all indexed.

Comment: i did it but that not work, Last rate for every record shows NULL

Comment: that is due to nature of left join.. i think

Comment: also due to d.Id > d2.Id (not one-on-one join). let me think what else could be done...

Comment: Added another variant. Not sure about the > sign: if the later rates have greater IDs then it should be as specified in my current query.

Comment: Actually, how many details might be corresponding to product, and how do you define the "current rate"? I would suggest you have some Date field somewhere.

Comment: basically current rate is the latest max id group by product Id,
last Rate is the just lower then max record.